# Using date condition in left outer join when date value is coming from different table

Tags: sql, oracle

Table Date_User has one column RUNDATE1, which store date (example - 2016-01-01). This date can be changed based on user request.

I am writing below query and it is throwing error:

```
Select A.NAME, B.DEPT_NAME, B.START_DATE, B.END_DATE
FROM TABLE A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TABLE B
      ON A.DEPT_ID = B.DEPT_ID AND
         DATE_USER.RUNDATE1 BETWEEN B.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE;
```

Above query is throwing error, because table Date_User is nowhere used in left outer join.

Could anyone please suggest how to modify the query.

Note: This is only sample query; Original query has 10 left outer join with similar type of date condition needed.

Comment: How many rows in DateUser? If only one then Cross join DateUser.

Answer (score 0):

If DATE_USER is neither TABLE A nor TABLE B, then you need to do an additional JOIN to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Select A.NAME, B.DEPT_NAME, B.START_DATE, B.END_DATE
FROM TABLE A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TABLE B
      ON A.DEPT_ID = B.DEPT_ID AND
LEFT JOIN DATE_USER ON 1 = 1 AND
         DATE_USER.RUNDATE1 BETWEEN B.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE;
```